# Draw the highlight blue color using UIImage or Code

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimage, uibutton

From http://replyz.com/c/1244746-does-anyone-know-the-exact-cgcolorref-used-to-create-the-selection-highlight-when-using-uitableviewcellselectionstyleblue#

I saw someone did it with Code and he said the highlighted color is from a UIImage.

Where can I find the image?

(I want to highlight a UIButton with the UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue color)

Comment: do screenshot and take color with default Xcode instruments (Pixie) or some another one.

Or look on this psd, maybe you will find what you want http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/ios-5-gui-psd-iphone-4s/

Answer (score 0):

I found the link http://replyz.com/c/1244746-does-anyone-know-the-exact-cgcolorref-used-to-create-the-selection-highlight-when-using-uitableviewcellselectionstyleblue# including some code which can be used to create the highlight. And I create a new UIImage with the Code.

Here is the code:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageForSelectedBlue {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    size_t num_locations = 2;
    CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    CGFloat components[8] = { 0.021, 0.548, 0.962, 1.000, 0.008, 0.364, 0.900, 1.000 };

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef selectionGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, selectionGradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);

    CGGradientRelease(selectionGradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace);

    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can set the background image of the button. It is more efficient.

```
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonBackgroundPressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```